# Getting the current position of the slide when you swipe on VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, swipe

So basically, i'm trying to get the position of the slide and then update the html by adding a class to that slide. But I can't figure out how to get the current position everytime I swipe, how to update the swipe_active data.

This is the vue js file.

```
mounted(){
 let element = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
 if (window.innerWidth< 550){
    window.mySwipe  =   Swipe (element, {
      startSlide: 1,
      auto: 0,
      autoRestart: true,
      continuous: true,
      disableScroll: true,
      stopPropagation: true,
      callback: function(index, element) {},
      transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
    });
  }
  this.swipe_active = window.mySwipe.getPos();
}
```

This is the html

```
  <div  :class="{black_swipe : swipe_active === 0  }"></div>
  <div  :class="{black_swipe : swipe_active === 1  }"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mounted` hook is called only once i.e when the component is finished mounting the DOM.

There is a `callback` property your have available in the config option you pass while creating a new Swipe instance. This property takes a function that will be called after every slide change

you can use this to update the `swipe_active` data.

```
mounted(){
 let element = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
 if (window.innerWidth< 550){
    window.mySwipe  = new  Swipe (element, {
      startSlide: 1,
      auto: 0,
      autoRestart: true,
      continuous: true,
      disableScroll: true,
      stopPropagation: true,
      callback: this.swipeCallback,
      transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
    });
  }
  this.swipe_active = window.mySwipe.getPos();
},

methods: {
    swipeCallback(index, element){
        this.swipe_active = window.mySwipe.getPos();
    }

}
```